# CSS & GSAP scaling graphical issues

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, gsap

On Firefox 28 the text does a very slight jitter at the end of the animation. In Chrome 34 the text becomes blurry. Looks like it got converted to a bitmap and scaled up. It stays blurry at the end of the animation. I'm shocked that on IE11 it works perfectly though.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fsljh

Not sure if it's something I'm doing wrong or if it's a bug/issue with the browsers. Trying to get a smooth, sharp, no-hiccup rotation/scaling if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `perspective` to the parent div of the element you are trying to animate.

You should see no blurry text in Chrome now: http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/qmHwe

**JS:**

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var sampleText = document.getElementById("sampleText");
// add perspective to its parent
// perspective applies to the children its added to
TweenMax.set(wrapper,{perspective:1000});
var bubAnim = TweenMax.to(sampleText, 3, {scale: 2.5, rotation:30});

bubAnim.play();
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <p id="sampleText">About Me</p>
 </div>
```

Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a greensock issue but a browser bug regard webkit.

Try this:

```
 TweenMax.set(element, {force3D:false});
```